# How do i size this/reduce left and right margins?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following plot, however it prints extremely narrowly with wide margins.

```
names = ['VCI', 'FRI', 'QII', 'VSI', 'WMI', 'PSI', 'GAI', 'CPI', 'FSIQ']
values = [102, 129, 129, 160, 149, 128, 134, 120, 118]

plt.subplot(132)

for x in range(len(values)):
   plt.scatter(names[x], values[x], marker = "$"+str(values[x])+"$", color = "black", s=300)

plt.plot(values[:6], color = 'black', linestyle = 'dashed')

plt.yticks(ticks=[40,50,60,70,80,90,100,110,120,130,140,150,160,170,180])
plt.minorticks_on()
plt.tick_params(axis='x', which='minor', bottom=False)

plt.show()
```

I tried using the following code, and while the plot itself was a usable size, the margins are way way too wide.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(20, 5))
```

What can I do to make the plot readable with narrow/no margins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1: Change `plt.subplot(132)` to `plt.subplot(111)`. What `plt.subplot(132)` means is that you want subplots in 1 row with 3 columns and you will be plotting in the 2nd subplot. Since you only want one plot, `111` means 1 row and 1 column and you will be plotting in the first subplot (the only subplot).

Option 2: You can remove the `plt.subplot(132)` line entirely if this is the only plot you are making, since `plt.scatter` will create a figure if none exists. If you have other plots being created in the code, you can change the line to `plt.figure()` to make a new figure that `plt.scatter` (and the other plotting commands) will use.

Comment: Thank you so much, I completely misunderstood what subplot meant.